# How to add text to shape without replacing previous old text

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a new shape and added text to the shape. But I want to add text the same shape later without replacing to old text.

```
Sub AddText_WithoutReplace()
Dim MyShape As Shape

Set MyShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 100, 100)
With MyShape
  .Name = "ThisShape_1"
  .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello"
End With

'Other Code

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ThisShape_1")).ShapeRange(1)_
 .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = " World"

End Sub
```

The old text (Hello) gets replaced and only new text (World) is added to the shape. I want to keep the old text and add new text to the shape to get "Hello World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid replacing old text with new text in the shape. The old text can be retained by changing the code line to:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ThisShape_1")).ShapeRange(1)_
 .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ThisShape_1"))_
 .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text & " World"
```

Text can also be added to a new line like:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ThisShape_1")).ShapeRange(1)_
     .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ThisShape_1"))_
     .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text & Chr(13) & " World"
```